# Unable to run compiled Java code - could not find or load main class

Tags: java

I am new to Java, and having problems running my compiled code.

I have a file called `AdditionApplication`. I compile this line:

```
javac -cp * AdditionApplication.java
```

This produces a file in the current directory called `AdditionApplication.class`

When I try and run the program with the code:

```
 java -cp * AdditionApplication
```

It gives the error `Error: Could not find or load main class AdditionApplication`

What could be a cause of such behavior?

**UPDATE**

So my code requires a jar file to be included in the initial compilation of the file. This seemed to only work if I had `javac - cp * AdditionApplication.java`, or if I specified the full path to the jar file.

When I switch over to us a `.` in 'java -cp . AdditionApplication', I get the error `NoClassDefFoundError` - which I gather occurs when the class which was initial reference during compilation is no longer available - why would that be the case?

Comment: Try ```java -cp . AdditionApplication```.

Comment: This may sound silly but does AdditionApplication has the correct signature `public static void main(String[] args)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classpath should be the directory with the files (not `*` unless they're jar files). Assuming you have a class file (and based on your other command you do), you add that folder to the classpath. Something like,

```
java -cp . AdditionApplication
```

Since you have a jar as well, you could do (on *NIX systems)

```
java -cp .:* AdditionApplication
```

**or** on Windows

```
java -cp .;* AdditionApplication
```

Comment: @Rickard Actually, [Setting the class path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html) says (in part) *Class path entries can contain the basename wildcard character *, which is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all the files in the directory with the extension `.jar` or `.JAR`.*